# Excel 2003 - VBA for looping through every cell in a row to provide attributes/formatting

Tags: vba, excel, automation, excel-2003

say I want to make the first row of the excel ss something like this:

```
                  .Rows("1:1").Select
                    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Weight = xlMedium
                        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    End With
                    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Weight = xlMedium
                        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    End With
                    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Weight = xlMedium
                        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    End With
                    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Weight = xlMedium
                        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    End With
```

only I want each individual cells to have the outline, not the entire selection. how can i say for each cell in row 1, do the above idea

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("1:1")
    c.Select
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
Next
```

But this may take a very long time, so set `Application.ScreenUpdating` to false before you start!

Answer (score 2):

Also set the  `xlInsideHorizontal`

Record a Macro, and the result was

```
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone

'I think this is what you were missing
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

Comment: Should be xlInsideVertical since it's on a row, right? (I think)

Comment: I tested this using Record Macro, so that was the code generated X-)